# How to get colored status bar icon?

Tags: android, notifications

In this screenshot, the app is showing colored status bar icon. Whenever I try to do so, my icons turn into mono color icons. I cant find any documentation regarding this. Can anyone please explain?

[image]

Comment: Notification icons are supposed to be colorless. Colored icons are a legacy feature that's enabled for apps targetting API lower than 21 (Lollipop).

Comment: @Pawel I am pretty sure this app is not below 21. This app gets regular updates. Apps below 21 can not push updates any more I believe.